# How to configure FastRWeb to use RServer built-in web server

Tags: r, rserve

I'm new to RServe (and FastRWeb). I installed RServe 1.7.0 as I want to use its built-in webserver. As I already have apache running on this machine I want to run RServe/FastRWeb on a custom port.

I did `cd /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/FastRWeb;sudo ./install.sh`, which created /var/FastRWeb/ directory tree.

I'm not seeing any configuration file that mentions port. The default /var/FastRWeb/code/rserve.conf looks like this:

```
socket /var/FastRWeb/socket
sockmod 0666
source /var/FastRWeb/code/rserve.R
control enable
```

I'm guessing that means it uses unix sockets, by default? So I think my question is what *exactly* do I have to put in (and remove from) that file to, say, have it listen on TCP port 8888? And is there anything else I need to do?  (I want to be able to connect from other machines, not just localhost.)

Possibly related, is I've looked at /var/FastRWeb/web/index.html and it contains javascript that is going to connect to `/cgi-bin/R/` Is that path specific to when using Apache, or is it going to be fine, as-is, when using RServe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an explanation of setting port in the [Rserve 1.7.0 release announcement](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/news.html). Therefore, at the top of rserve.conf, I added this line: `http.port 8888`  Then I used the `start` script (as root), to start it.

This got me halfway as now `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` works, but gives me a page that says:

```
Error in try(.http.request("/", NULL, NULL, c(48, 6f, 73, 74, 3a, 20,  : 
  could not find function ".http.request"
```

The second half of the solution is to add this to the top of /var/FastRWeb/code/rserve.R:

```
library(FastRWeb)
.http.request <- FastRWeb:::.http.request
```

Then start things going by running `/var/FastRWeb/code/start`. There is no default handler, so you can test it with `http://127.0.0.1:8888/info`. Or a more interesting example is `http://127.0.0.1:8888/example1.png` (to view a chart) or `http://127.0.0.1:8888/example2` (to view a mix of html and chart)

Note: I did not delete or edit any other configuration to get this working. That means we also have the unix socket listening. If that is not needed remove those two lines from the Rserve.conf file.

If you want it listening on all IP addresses, not just localhost, then add `remote enable` to your Rserve.conf file. **NOTE:** Make sure you understand the security consequences before opening your server to the world.

So, after those two changes, my `/var/FastRWeb/code/Rserve.conf` file looks like:

```
http.port 8888
remote enable
source /var/FastRWeb/code/rserve.R
control enable
```

Comment: I know this is from a while ago, but thanks for this. Have you been having success with FastRWeb? I rolled my own equivalent in Ruby, and am thinking about going this way to better handle concurrent connections.

Comment: @Brandon No, it all felt too experimental, and I never got back to it. (I just checked and there have been a few later releases of Rserve, so it may be better now.)

Comment: Thanks for the input Darren. I've played around with it a bit tonight and it seems to be performing as expected. All it has to beat is my hacky solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [Jay Emerson's write-up from a while back](http://jayemerson.blogspot.com/2011/10/setting-up-fastrwebrserve-on-ubuntu.html) about how to use RServe as a backend for web-driven analysis?  As I recall, one still uses Apache for the redirection, rather than an explicit port as you surmise here.

Jay's setup was very impressive. He used Rserve to provide mixed table/chart pages written via the grid package, all very slick and very fast, based of an immense data set (from a UN agency, or the World Bank, or something).  But I can't find a link to that report right now...

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I had found that page, but as you say, it is for use with Apache. The FastRWeb page says: "FastRWeb can be run on any webserver that supports either CGI or PHP. As of version 1.1 it can be also used directly with the built-in webserver in Rserve 1.7 and higher." That sounds to me like Apache should not be needed?